# how to save current timestamp in database in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I wanna to save current timestamp for every record that saves in database in cakephp.So I have a field in my table on database that its type is TIMESTAMP and its default value is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. but when I wanna save data it does not work.

Comment: can you give your table structure ?

Comment: [link](https://s32.postimg.org/meuqbwf2d/table.jpg)

Comment: Change `datetime` to `timestamp`

Comment: I changed it but it`s not working.

Comment: Can you give me again your latest table structure?

Comment: [link](https://s32.postimg.org/7gephcwit/table.jpg)

Comment: Record inserted in database? But do not enter current timestamp in `date` field? Am i right?

Comment: No noting saved on table.

Comment: can you give me your insert query?

Comment: my code is                                                                                                $uid = $this->Auth->User()['id'];
        $damage = $this->Damages->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $damage = $this->Damages->patchEntity($damage, $this->request->data);
         $damage['user_id'] = $uid;
           $this->Damages->save($damage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified) of version 2.x

> Using created and modified By defining a created and/or modified field
>   in your database table as datetime fields (default null), CakePHP will
>   recognize those fields and populate them automatically whenever a
>   record is created or saved to the database (unless the data being
>   saved already contains a value for these fields).
>
> The created and modified fields will be set to the current date and
>   time when the record is initially added. The modified field will be
>   updated with the current date and time whenever the existing record is
>   saved.
>
> If you have created or modified data in your $this->data (e.g. from a
>   Model::read or Model::set) before a Model::save() then the values will
>   be taken from $this->data and not automagically updated. If you don’t
>   want that you can use unset($this->data['Model']['modified']), etc.
>   Alternatively you can override the Model::save() to always do it for
>   you:

```
class AppModel extends Model {

public function save($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()) {
    // Clear modified field value before each save
    $this->set($data);
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['modified'])) {
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['modified']);
    }
    return parent::save($this->data, $validate, $fieldList);
}
}
```

> If you are saving data with a fieldList and the created and modified
>   fields are not present in the whitelist, the fields will continue to
>   have the values automatically assigned. When included in the
>   fieldList, the created and modified fields work like any other field.